# Need angular 2+ currency pipe to show 2 decimals and accept various user input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-pipe

I have an input that I need to display currency in.  I need it to always show 2 decimal places and no dollar symbol.  I decided to use the `number` pipe since I was not concerned about the dollar symbol.  This input is editable by the user but when I use the pipe, I am getting undesirable behavior.

**Here is what the code looks like for the input:**

```
<input type="text"
[ngModel]="myCurrencyVar | number:'1.2-2'"
(ngModelChange)="myCurrencyVar=$event">
```

The problem with this approach is that if the user wants to enter something like `$2.55`, as they type, the value will jump to `2.00` when they type the digit `2` and then they have to hit the `delete` key twice to clear out the zeros, then when they hit the `5` key it will become `$2.50` then the user has to `delete` the last `zero` again to enter in the final `5`.

**I also tried:**

```
<input type="text"
[ngModel]="myCurrencyVar | number:'1.0-2'"
(ngModelChange)="myCurrencyVar=$event">
```

But that approach will show something like `$2.5` when it needs to be `$2.50` on screen.  I need it to show the cents all the time without having this weird behavior.

**I also tried with the currency pipe:**

```
currency:'USD':'':'1.2-2'"
```

Is there any way to accomplish having 2 decimals always displaying without it acting all goofy when the user types?

---

**UPDATE 1**

This is what I changed it to after I got the suggestion to update to two-way binding, but the model doesn't seem to update when I change the dollar amount in the input:

```
<input type="text"
([ngModel])="myCurrencyVar"
currencyMask [options]="{ prefix: '' }">
```

**UPDATE 2**

My solution to the screen update problem was to go back to using `(ngModelChange)` and adding an `update()` function after the `$event` was passed in like so:

```
<input type="text"
[ngModel]="myCurrencyVar | number:'1.0-2'"
(ngModelChange)="myCurrencyVar=$event;update()">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, I've used to pipes to only change read-only data or how data is displayed. For changing the formatting of an input in Angular, I reverted to using custom directives.

Here's a directive that I think accomplishes what you're trying to do:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask

Comment: hmm... this directive you suggest is good, but for some reason the ngModel isn't being updated anymore.

Comment: Go ahead and combine your ngModel into [(ngModel)]="myCurrencyVar " instead of splitting the output and input. Notice my banana casing on the ngModel.

Comment: No dice with bananas in boxes.  The ngModel is only being updated when I remove the `currencyMask` directive...

Comment: @starfigher104, I _think_ the model is being updated but its not being reflected on the screen until I update another box without this directive on it.  For some reason, this directive is not triggering the angular view update procedure (I dont know what its called)

Comment: I have it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zt81so   I'm noticing the model isnt being set.

Comment: I didnt mention earlier that there is the following going on as well: `(input)="update();"`.  So, I have an `update()` function which takes the values of other input boxes and does some calculations.  Everything works fine as long as I am editing an input without this directive on it.  The model is being updated but wont manifest on the screen unless i edit a different input box without the directive.

Comment: @starfigher104: I added one solution that I found up top.

Comment: I got it working. <input currencyMask  [ngModel]="vartest" (ngModelChange)="vartest = $event" /> Also updated the stackblitz

Comment: What we had before with the bananaCase should work once that issue for the package is resolved.